# WordPress in Docker on Azure with Azure File Share

Tags: wordpress, azure, docker

### UPDATED QUESTION

Taking another run at this to hopefully provide a lot more concrete details in case anyone can see what I'm missing to get this working.

**STEPS**

1. Created App Service with Linux Docker Container, configured as follows:

[image]

[image]

2. Created Storage Account as follows:

[image]

[image]

3. Created a File Share as follows:

[image]

4. Added path mapping to App Service as follows:

[image]

5. Added the appropriate WordPress database settings to the application settings in the App Service configuration, and save the changes.
6. Hit App Service URL, do the WordPress installation steps, log in, and navigate to media library
7. Upload image, get no errors with the upload but the image doesn't appear in the media library:

[image]

8. Image file DOES appear in the Azure File Share:

[image]

9. Try to browse to image URL shown in WordPress media library and get a 502:

[image]

10. Try to browse to URL for the image shown in the Azure File Share, and get this error:

[image]

So from what I can tell the Docker container is mounting the Azure File Share fine, but the HTTP access to the files isn't working, and I'm not sure what in the configuration or permissions I need to change to allow public read access to the uploads through the WordPress site.

Hope the outlining of the steps I took and the screenshots help clarify what I did and what's not working.

---

### ORIGINAL QUESTION

I'm in the process of trying to get WordPress deployed on Azure and am stuck how to use Azure File Storage to handle the media files, specifically how to get them to be able to be served over HTTP.

Currently in my testing I'm building a custom Docker image locally, pushing that to my Azure Container Registry, deploying that into an App Service, and I'm pointing to an Azure MySQL database. That's all working fine (other than I can't SSH into the container, but I'm not super concerned about that).

I also have a storage account and an Azure File Share configured, so I went into the App Service configuration and added a path mapping with a mount point of /var/www/html/wp-content/media and added the appropriate stuff to the WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA in application settings. I've also tried /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads as the mount point but got the same results, which are ...

I can upload files fine into the WordPress media library, and they show up when I browse the file storage in the Azure portal. Uploaded images don't, however, appear in the WordPress media gallery; there's just empty boxes where the images should be, and if I browse to the image URL, I get a 502 error.

So the filesystem permissions seem to be fine with respect to being able to write to the file share from the container. The missing piece seems to be the ability to serve the media files, and I'm stuck on how to go about solving that piece of it.

And I'm all ears if there's a simpler way to go about all of this in general, though I feel like if I can get the media files served in a browser I'll be a pretty happy camper.

Thanks for any guidance anyone can provide!

Comment: You have a lot of description but no details on exactly what is configured. The location for WordPress media is /wp-content/uploads. If you mount the Azure File Share on that directory, you should not have any problems, assuming the correct role granting access. You mention that files upload OK, but images do not. More details are required on what problem you are seeing. The 502 error probably means that PHP threw an exception. What do the logs show? I have a production site running WordPress with Azure File Share and I did not experience the issues that you have seen.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using a mount path of /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads as well with the same result, so I'll dig into it more and see what the logs say. "Files" is a generic term -- all files upload fine, but images don't show a preview in the media library, and browsing to them throws the 502. I'll wrap my head around where Azure is throwing logs and see what I can see. Thanks again for the thoughts.

Comment: I use **WP Log Viewer** on WordPress to see the logs. You need to manually add three entries to wp-config.php. If there are log errors a red number appears in the WordPress Dashboard title bar. Very nice way to see what is happening under the covers with warnings and errors. The log entries are formatted for a cleaner presentation.

Comment: Update: in my first comment I meant **/path-to-wordpress-files/wp-content/uploads**

Comment: @MattWoodward did you ever find a fix for this? We're seeing the same issue with a SilverStripe CMS.

Comment: @Patrick unfortunately I didn't ever figure this out -- I ran things on AWS LIghtsail instead. I'm now revisiting WordPress on Azure because Microsoft offers better credits for non-profits and Azure now has a WordPress AppService solution that "just works" with Azure Blob Storage. I will say that WordPress on Azure is quite slow compared to even cheap shared hosting (based on my googling it relates to how Azure does file operations) and bulk uploading all my assets to transfer from AWS to Azure has proven HORRIBLY slow to the point where I may have to give up. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: We found that this was our fix.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322091/laravel-in-docker-on-azure-webapp-cant-serve-images-from-mounted-file-storage

Answer (score 0):

"By default, all Azure storage accounts have encryption in transit enabled. This means that when you mount a file share over SMB or access it via the FileREST protocol (such as through the Azure portal, PowerShell/CLI, or Azure SDKs), Azure Files **will only allow the connection if it is made with SMB 3.x with encryption or HTTPS**" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-planning 
I think its not possible to access file in Azure Files SMB through http, CMIIW. In my case, configure it into https solve the accessing media file problem. Or if you only want to serve uploads directory, there is an easier way by using Azure Blob Storage and Microsoft Azure Storage Plugin in wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for the information and thoughts. That makes sense to me if I were trying to access the files directly from the file share, but since I'm mounting the file share as a path mapping in the app service/docker container, in theory at that point it's like any other local path on the container's disk. If I'm not off-base with that line of thinking then it seems like the issue is either permissions (but I can read/write from the app itself fine; it just won't serve the files as expected over https), or maybe I have to do something with volumes in my Dockerfile? I'll keep digging! Thanks again.